# How to test Async Storage with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, jestjs, asyncstorage

I'm building an app with React Native. I want to minimize how often I communicate to the database, so I make heavy use of AsyncStorage. There's a lot of room for bugs in the translation between DB and AsyncStorage though. Therefore, I want to make sure that AsyncStorage has the data I believe it does by running automated tests against it. Surprisingly, I haven't found any information on how to do that online. My attempts to do it on my own haven't worked out.

Using Jest:

```js
it("can read asyncstorage", () => {
return AsyncStorage.getItem('foo').then(foo => {
  expect(foo).not.toBe("");
});  });
```

This method failed with an error:

```js
TypeError: RCTAsyncStorage.multiGet is not a function
```

Removing the return will cause it to run instantly without waiting for the value and improperly pass the test.

I got hit with the exact same error when I tried to test it using the await keyword:

```js
it('can read asyncstorage', async () => {
this.foo = "";
await AsyncStorage.getItem('foo').then(foo => {
    this.foo = foo;
});
expect(foo).not.toBe(""); });
```

Any suggestions on how to successfully run assertions against the values in AsyncStorage? I'd prefer to continue using Jest but if it can only be done with some alternate testing library I'm open to that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My original answer just pointed at how the author of react-native-simple-store had dealt with the mocking. I've updated my answer with my own mocking that removes Jason's hard-coded mock responses.

[Jason Merino](https://github.com/jasonmerino) has a nice simple approach to this in [https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store/blob/master/**tests**/index-test.js#L31-L64](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store/blob/master/__tests__/index-test.js#L31-L64)

```js
jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
AsyncStorage: {
    setItem: jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(null);
        });
    }),
    multiSet:  jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(null);
        });
    }),
    getItem: jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(JSON.stringify(getTestData()));
        });
    }),
    multiGet: jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(multiGetTestData());
        });
    }),
    removeItem: jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(null);
        });
    }),
    getAllKeys: jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(['one', 'two', 'three']);
        });
    })
  }
}));
```

My own mock:

```js
const items = {};

jest.mock('react-native', () => ({

AsyncStorage: {        

    setItem: jest.fn((item, value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {        
    items[item] = value;
            resolve(value);
        });
    }),
    multiSet:  jest.fn((item, value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    items[item] = value;
            resolve(value);
        });
    }),
    getItem: jest.fn((item, value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(items[item]);
        });
    }),
    multiGet: jest.fn((item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(items[item]);
        });
    }),
    removeItem: jest.fn((item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(delete items[item]);
        });
    }),
    getAllKeys: jest.fn((items) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(items.keys());
        });
    })
  }
}));
```

Comment: This solution will work only for your use case, the solution below should be the accepted one!

Comment: @Ouadie it needs editing so `multiGet` and `multiSet` are defined. @brian-case was asking specifically about `multiGet`. I'll dig out how I ended up mocking mine, avoiding the hard-coded responses to `resolve()`

Comment: Getting 'Cannot find module 'AsyncStorage' from 'react-native-implementation.js' ' in my test when using your mock - any idea why? :) @jaygooby

Comment: @jaygooby, instead of `items.keys()` should be `Object.keys(items)`

Comment: Because of the `const items = {}`: `The module factory of 'jest.mock()' is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: items`.

Comment: Thanks, FYI you might wanna update your answer since AsyncStorage has been moved out of 'react-native'. 

From the link you pasted:
```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage', () => ({
```

Answer (score 57):

For everyone who sees this question in > 2019:

Since [Nov 2020](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/releases/tag/v1.13.2), **AsyncStorage was renamed back to [@react-native-async-storage/async-storage"](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage)**, which causes this warning to appear if you're importing it from `react-native`:

```bash
Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release.
```

The new module includes its own mock, so you don't have to worry about writing your own anymore.

[Per the project's documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest/), you can set it up in 2 different ways:

### With mocks directory

- In your project root directory, create a `__mocks__/@react-native-community` directory.
- Inside that folder, create async-storage.js file.
- Inside that file, export Async Storage mock.

  ```js
  export default from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock'
  ```

Jest should then mock `AsyncStorage` by default in all your tests. If it doesn't, try calling `jest.mock(@react-native-async-storage/async-storage)` at the top of your test file.

### With Jest setup file

- In your Jest config (probably in `package.json` or `jest.config.js`) add the setup file's location:

  ```json
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["./path/to/jestSetupFile.js"]
  }
  ```
- Inside your setup file, set up the AsyncStorage mock:

  ```js
  import mockAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock';

  jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage', () => mockAsyncStorage);
  ```

**If you're using TypeScript**, using the 2nd option (Jest setup file) is way easier, since with the 1st one (mocks directory) it won't associate `@types/react-native-community__async-storage` with the mock automatically.

Comment: I don't see any `/jest` folder inside the `async-storage` folder :( jest is throwing an error that it can find the path you specified

Comment: @betoharres, are you using `@react-native-community/async-storage` or React Native's built-in `AsyncStorage`?

Comment: @david-catillo Yes! I was like 1 version behind from them to add the mock to the library. Ref to my solution here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage/issues/39#issuecomment-481971075

Comment: I also don't see a jest folder in my `@react-native-community/async-storage` folder. Just a `node_modules` folder. And I'm on v1.3.4 which appears to be current.

Comment: Note: the package mentioned above does not work with an expo project yet: https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/172

Comment: For Expo:

Here is a simple way to stub out AsyncStorage either in your test or in your jest setup file:

jest.mock("@react-native-community/async-storage", () => ({
  AsyncStorage: {
    clear: jest.fn().mockName("clear"),
    getAllKeys: jest.fn().mockName("getAllKeys"),
    getItem: jest.fn().mockName("getItem"),
    removeItem: jest.fn().mockName("removeItem"),
    setItem: jest.fn().mockName("setItem")
  }
}));

Answer (score 27):

May be you can try something like this:

**mockStorage.js**

```js
export default class MockStorage {
  constructor(cache = {}) {
    this.storageCache = cache;
  }

  setItem = jest.fn((key, value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return (typeof key !== 'string' || typeof value !== 'string')
        ? reject(new Error('key and value must be string'))
        : resolve(this.storageCache[key] = value);
    });
  });

  getItem = jest.fn((key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      return this.storageCache.hasOwnProperty(key)
        ? resolve(this.storageCache[key])
        : resolve(null);
    });
  });

  removeItem = jest.fn((key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return this.storageCache.hasOwnProperty(key)
        ? resolve(delete this.storageCache[key])
        : reject('No such key!');
    });
  });

  clear = jest.fn((key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  resolve(this.storageCache = {}));
  });

  getAllKeys = jest.fn((key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(Object.keys(this.storageCache)));
  });
}
```

and inside your **test file**:

```js
import MockStorage from './MockStorage';

const storageCache = {};
const AsyncStorage = new MockStorage(storageCache);

jest.setMock('AsyncStorage', AsyncStorage)

// ... do things
```

Comment: Getting 'Cannot find module 'AsyncStorage' from 'myFileName.js' ' , in spite of trying to import it from 'react-native' - any ideas? :)

Comment: Should be accepted answer since it most clearly answers the origin question

Comment: How do you clear the `storageCache` ? I tried `beforeEach` with `await AsyncStorage.clear()`  but it does not affect the `storageCache` of the mock

Comment: I am using this answer as solution, but I'm having the same issue as @jhm. Any progress? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Install the module using the command :
Run this command from the root directory of the project.

```
npm install --save mock-async-storage
```

In the project root directory create `__mocks__\@react-native-community` folder. Inside that create a file async-storage.js.
Code in async-storage.js

```
export default from '@react-native-community/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock'
```

Inside package.json configure the jest as follows:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns" : ["/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/(?!(lib))"]
  },
```

Here I am using jest-expo for testing. If you are using jest then the preset value will be jest not jest-expo.

In the project root directory create a file called jest.config.js
Configuration inside the  jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
      './setup-tests.js',
    ],
  };
```

In the project root directory create a file called setup-tests.js. Code in this file is :

```
import MockAsyncStorage from 'mock-async-storage';

const mockImpl = new MockAsyncStorage();
jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage', () => mockImpl);
```

In the project root directory create the test file. Here I am calling it Example.test.js.

```
import  AsyncStorage  from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

beforeEach(() => {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
    // console.log(`After the data is being reset :`)
    // console.log(AsyncStorage)
});

it('can read asyncstorage', async () => {

    await AsyncStorage.setItem('username', 'testUser')
    let usernameValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username')
    // console.log(`After the data is being set :`)
    // console.log(AsyncStorage)
    expect(usernameValue).toBe('testUser')
});
```

Here setting the value of **username** to testUser using AsyncStorage.setItem. Then fetching the value using getItem function.
The test case is to compare whether the usernameValue is equal to testUser.
If yes then the test case passes else the test case will fail.

Using beforeEach so that every time a test case is being run Asyncstorage is being cleared and is empty.
If needed one can check what is present in Asyncstorage using console.log

Run the command *yarn test* to run the tests. The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1- add folder `__mocks__` in root project

2- add folder `@react-native-async-storage` in `__mocks__` folder

3- add file `async-storage.js` in `@react-native-async-storage`

4- add code:

```
let db = {};

export default {
    setItem: (item, value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db[item] = value;
            resolve(value);
        });
    },
    multiSet: (item, fun) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            for (let index = 0; index < item.length; index++) {
                db[item[index][0]] = item[index][1];
            }
            fun()
            resolve(value);
        });
    },
    getItem: (item, value= null) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(db[item]);
        });
    },
    multiGet: (item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(db[item]);
        });
    },
    removeItem: (item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(delete db[item]);
        });
    },
    getAllKeys: (db) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(db.keys());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [jest.setMock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestsetmockmodulename-moduleexports) could be in this case better than jest.mock so we can use `react-native` with no problem just mocking the `AsyncStorage` like that:

```
jest.setMock('AsyncStorage', {
  getItem: jest.fn(
    item =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({ myMockObjectToReturn: 'myMockObjectToReturn' });
      })
  ),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue running jest with latest version of Expo and solved it following the 'jest setup file' option in the directions at https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest/.

Note that AsyncStorage was (for whatever reason) renamed\moved back to "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and no longer contains "community" in its package name.