# Unit testing AsyncStorage in React Native with Jest

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am learning React Native and Jest testing.

I have a piece of code where I am storing some value in an AsyncStorage when a button is clicked. When the button is clicked I call the below method.

```
saveState = () => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('saveState', 'button clicked');      
}
```

Now I would want to unit test the above method to see if my Async storage is working fine or not.

I was able to create a snapshot and also test remaining functionalities of the method but not this one. But I am not quite familiar in how to do so?

2nd edit ------

```
jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
    setItem: jest.fn()
}));


describe('<MyComponent/>', () => {
  let tnCScreen
  let props
  let instance

  beforeEach(() => {
    tnCScreen = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />)
    instance = tnCScreen.instance()
  })

  test('test saveState method is called', () => {
    expect(instance.saveState()).toBeCalled
    expect(AsyncStorage.setItem).toBeCalledWith('saveState', 'button clicked');
  })

})
```

When I try the above I get below error

```
expect(received).toBeCalledWith(...expected)
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
Received has value: undefined
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

In your test file, you can mock any external module and then check that it was called with the right arguments like so:

```js
jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage', () => ({
  setItem: jest.fn(),
}));

// in your test:
expect(AsyncStorage.setItem).toBeCalledWith('saveState', 'button clicked');
```

Comment: Hi Marek, I have edited the above with the solution you have provided, but I get the above error. Also, I could not change to '@react-native-community/async-storage' as our project is using Async storage from react native. Apart from that any guesses what could be going wrong?

Comment: I understand you are importing AsyncStorage from react-native? It is now deprecated, so if that is the case, consider adding the `@react-native-community/async-storage` package and then adjusting the jest.mock to what I provided above. Otherwise, this past question can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952566/how-to-test-async-storage-with-jest